# pgfplots: stacking plots in positive and negative y direction in the same diagram

Tags: pgfplots

I have several data files which I want to plot in the following manner:

[image]

I achieved this with the following code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{total.dos}
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   
1  2  0 -2  0  2  0 -2  
2  4  0 -4  0  4  0 -4  
3  2  0 -2  0  2  0 -2  
4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
5  1  0 -1  0  0  0  0 
6  2  0 -2  0  0  0  0 
7  1  0 -1  0  0  0  0 
8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xlabel={Energy [eV]}, ylabel={Intensity}, no markers]
    \addplot [fill=red,draw=none] table [x index=0,y index=5] {total.dos};
    \addplot [fill=red,draw=red,fill opacity=0.25] table [x index=0,y index=1] {total.dos};
    \addplot [fill=red,draw=none] table [x index=0, y index=7] {total.dos};
    \addplot [fill=red,draw=red,fill opacity=0.25] table [x index=0,y index=3] {total.dos};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**My Question:**
How can I stack several of those plots?

It should look similar to this:

[image]

The problem is that normal stacking doesn't work because this would stack every `addplot` which leads to wrong output since some `y` columns of my data have positive and some have negative values for the same `x` value and `pgfplots` stacks the plots only in one direction (either positive or negative). But I need to make `pgfplots` group some `addplot`s, while within the respective groups there is no stacking, and then let it stack the groups. Is this possible?

**Update:**
I have changed the title of my question since the discussions in the comment section revealed that the crucial point is to make `pgfplots` plot in the positive and negative `y` direction at the same time. This way I get the plots to appear the way I want.

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm following the question. What exactly is stopping you from putting all `addplot`s (regardless of the file) in the same axis environment?

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: The problem is, that I have positive and negative data columns, but `pgfplots` does just stack in one direction. So some of the data columns "cancel out each other". I could provide an example if you want.

Comment: I'm still not following, the plots are simply stacked in the order that you place them...

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: I also tried to change the order of the `addplot`s. That changed the result a bit but not essentially. The problem remains, that `pgfplots` either stacks in the positive or in the negative `y` direction.

Comment: You can probably force it with pgflayers.  I'm on a phone at the moment, so I can't help much.

Comment: Another problem arises from the structure of my data files. The columns that are responsible for the opaque part of my example plot contain not only the right (visible) opaque part of the plot but also the data from the left non-opaque part (but that is overlapped by the non-opaque data column) which would also complicate the normal stacking.

Comment: It seems like you've moved the goal posts a bit. Anyway, given the possible complexity of implementing what you're asking for in LaTeX, it's probably time to learn your way around bash and awk or python. Scripting languages are a better option for reformatting your files to make them more friendly for the task at hand.

Comment: @Philipp: I find this question a bit confusing. In your second image, what is the data used for the blue areas? It looks to me like the positive fully opaque blue area is the sequence `0, 4, 1, 6, 0` stacked on top of the `0, 2, 4, 2, 0` series from the first example. Is that correct? Also, you should make your examples more minimal: There's no need for the `external` library or the `THIS WAS: TOTAL` row.

Comment: @Jake: I'm sorry if my question is confusing. The second image was included simply to show roughly what I want to achieve. I created it by including another data file with different coordinates in the plot, so it's not really stacked but appears that way. Should I try to rewrite my question to make some points a little clearer? Furthermore, how many comments are allowed for a question? Is there a better way to communicate problems about the question?

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: I guess I could achieve the reformatting of my data via `pgfplotstable` using `y expr=\thisrowno{1} + \thisrowno{2}` or the like. It would take more time to compile but should be possible. But then I still have some problems left, i.e. the stacking in positive and negative `y` direction. I could rephrase my question to bring out this point a little better.

Comment: I reduced your plot code to minimise it. If you feel that I have taken too much out, then you may of course roll back. I believe that I've left the important bits in though.

Comment: Are columns *always* positive or negative? i.e. never some positive and some negative values in the same column?

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: Yes, they are always either positive or negative, never mixed (except for the `x` column but I guess that doesn't count).

Comment: Then as long as you know which columns are positive and which are negative, this can be done with two axes. I'll write it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the below is close to what you want. The trick is to add only the positive columns in a stacked plot, and only the negative columns in another plot that pretends to share the same axes. To work, both the visible and invisible axes must have the same domain. I also used the units pgfplots library to separate the units out.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\pgfplotsset{width=6cm,compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{total.dos}
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   
1  2  0 -2  0  2  0 -2  
2  4  0 -4  0  4  0 -4  
3  2  0 -2  0  2  0 -2  
4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
5  1  0 -1  0  0  0  0 
6  2  0 -2  0  0  0  0 
7  1  0 -1  0  0  0  0 
8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  stack plots=y,
  xlabel={Energy},
  x unit={eV},
  ylabel={Intensity},
  no markers,
  ymin=-10,
  ymax=10
]
  \addplot [fill=red,draw=none] table [x index=0,y index=5] {total.dos}\closedcycle;
  \addplot [fill=blue,draw=none,fill opacity=0.25] table [x index=0,y index=1] {total.dos}\closedcycle;
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
  stack plots=y,
  no markers,
  ymin=-10,
  ymax=10,
  xtick=\empty,
  ytick=\empty,
  axis x line=none,
  axis y line=none
]
  \addplot [fill=red,draw=none] table [x index=0, y index=7] {total.dos}\closedcycle;
  \addplot [fill=blue,draw=none,fill opacity=0.25] table [x index=0,y index=3] {total.dos}\closedcycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the idea with the second axis - certainly wouldn't have thought about that. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @MarkSEveritt: can you include the preamble as well? It seems that some other library is needed to use `x unit={eV}`. Also am wondering, was there something else you did to get that image, as your graph looks very nice.

Comment: @PeterGrill: He used the preamble from my above example and added `\usepgfplotslibrary{units}` to provide the `x unit` command.

Comment: @Philipp: Thanks. I did not see that in your preamble. However, Mark's graph still looks nicer than what I get, wondering if it is the bold font.

Comment: @PeterGrill: My mistake, I'll put the missed pgfplots library into the answer. Otherwise this plot has the same preamble as in the question. It was converted using Preview on a Mac though, so it may have been subjected to stronger than normal hinting on the text. When I tried to upload this as a pdf the uploader was freaking out and making it weird and pixellated for some reason, thus the conversion this time.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Sorry, had a typo in my comment. You're right `\usepgfplotslibrary{units}` wasn't in my preamble and Mark seems indeed to have changed something I first didn't notice.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I also made the plot relatively small (6cm wide) which may alter the look. I updated the code to be a working example. I usually throw in a `scale only axis` into the axis definitions to fix only the axis sizes for consistency.

Comment: I guess this off topic, but am curious as to why your text seems bold compared to what I get. I normally just grab the image of the screen on the Mac, but just tried Preview and get the same results as from TeXWorks, even saving as PNG form Preview does not yield the image as it show here.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Have you tried the updated code in the answer? I'd be interested to know if it's still different.

Comment: Just loaded your new code and uploaded [the image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5mVO6.png) I get from using Preview on Mac and saving as PNG and have exactly the size you have but the text is not bold.  To compare I edited your answer (but didn't save) the images do look different.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Perhaps SE does something to the image when it's uploaded. It was behaving very strangely a minute ago with image uploads.

Comment: I thought that too, and edited your question to include both images one below to other so I can see both at the same time and that does not seem to be the case. The image I linked to was the one uploaded via TeX.SE

Comment: @PeterGrill: I'm at a loss then... What version of OSX are you using? I'm on Lion. Perhaps the rendering technology was changed between versions.

Comment: Perhaps. I am 10.6.8 which I think is the version before Lion.

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completeness I will add a different answer to my own question since it solves the problem of stacking in only one `y` direction without the need of a second axis. Actually `pgfplots` is able to stack in the positive and negative `y` direction at the same time if the data files contain positive as well as negative values.

I came across the solution while learning a bit more about the `pgfplotstable` package. Actually one could achieve the same result by manipulating the data with external tools (like python or bash) as Mark suggested in one of his comments. I prefered to let `LaTeX` do the job, so that I can use my data files directly.

My solution:

```
\documentclass{standalone}   

\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\pgfplotsset{width=6cm,compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{lightred}{red!25!white}
\colorlet{lightblue}{blue!25!white}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{total.dos}
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   
1  2  0 -2  0  2  0 -2  
2  4  0 -4  0  4  0 -4  
3  2  0 -2  0  2  0 -2  
4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
5  1  0 -1  0  0  0  0 
6  2  0 -2  0  0  0  0 
7  1  0 -1  0  0  0  0 
8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread{total.dos}\total

% sort original file from highest to lowest value
\pgfplotstablesort[sort cmp=float >]{\totalsorted}{\total}

% first auxiliary table derived from \total: \totaldummy
\pgfplotstableset{
create on use/x/.style={create col/copy column from table={\total}{[index] 0}},
create on use/dummya/.style={create col/copy column from table={\total}{[index] 1}},
create on use/dummyb/.style={create col/copy column from table={\total}{[index] 3}},
create on use/a/.style={create col/copy column from table={\total}{[index] 5}},
create on use/b/.style={create col/copy column from table={\total}{[index] 7}},
create on use/c/.style={create col/expr={\thisrow{dummya} - \thisrow{a}}},
create on use/d/.style={create col/expr={\thisrow{dummyb} - \thisrow{b}}}}
% create a new table:
\pgfplotstablenew[columns={x, dummya, dummyb, a, b, c, d}] {\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\total}} {\totaldummy}

% second auxiliary table derived from \totalsorted: \totalsorteddummy
\pgfplotstableset{
create on use/x/.style={create col/copy column from table={\totalsorted}{[index] 0}},
create on use/dummya/.style={create col/copy column from table={\totalsorted}{[index] 3}},
create on use/dummyb/.style={create col/copy column from table={\totalsorted}{[index] 1}},
create on use/a/.style={create col/copy column from table={\totalsorted}{[index] 7}},
create on use/b/.style={create col/copy column from table={\totalsorted}{[index] 5}},
create on use/c/.style={create col/expr={\thisrow{dummya} - \thisrow{a}}},
create on use/d/.style={create col/expr={\thisrow{dummyb} - \thisrow{b}}}}
% create a new table:
\pgfplotstablenew[columns={x, dummya, dummyb, a, b, c, d}] {\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\total}} {\totalsorteddummy}

% Concatenate the two dummy tables
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\result}{\totaldummy}
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\result}{\totalsorteddummy}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  stack plots=y,
  xlabel={Energy},
  ylabel={Intensity},
  x unit={eV}
]
\addplot [no markers, fill=lightblue, draw=blue] table [x=x, y=c] {\result};
\addplot [no markers, fill=blue, draw=blue] table [x=x, y=a] {\result};
\addplot [no markers, fill=lightred, draw=red] table [x=x, y=c] {\result};
\addplot [no markers, fill=red, draw=red] table [x=x, y=a] {\result};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This results in the following picture:

[image]

This way I achieved exactly the look I was aiming for: the right lobes of the plot are more lightly colored than the left ones and the lightly colored regions are coated by a darker line.
To get the right look the data values had to be sorted according to the `x` values. This is done by using `\pgfplotstablesort[sort cmp=float >]{\resulttable}{\table or filename}` which sorts the data from highest to lowest `x` value. If one doesn't sort the values the following look would result:

[image]

So one could leave out the sorting step if the same colors are used for `draw` and `fill` or `draw=none` is used.

Comment: If this solves your question better than my answer does, then you should consider marking this as the correct one.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: The central point of my question (the stacking problem) is solved by your answer and in an easier fashion than in my answer which only gives the better results for my special data files. Furthermore it was only in the course of our discussion in the commentary section that I realized which way was to go in order to solve my problem.

Comment: Fair enough! I won't argue too hard. ;)