# pgfplots: problem with stacked histograms

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I want to plot data for a node that has several inflows and one outflow, using stacked histograms. I want the plot to look like this:

[image: This is what I want]

First, I have tried stacked histograms (`ybar stacked`, see the code below), where I draw the negative series first and then add it to the first series. Unfortunately, it does work, even if it works with lines and  `area style`:

[image] [image]

Then I tried using separate `axis` environment for positive and negative values, as suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42158/10760). The problem is that the stacked histogram breaks down once I change `ymin` - is this a bug?

[image: this works] [image: this does not]

*My question is:*  is there some way to make this work, other than the hack I used to create the first figure?
(There, I am stacking the columns manually - OK for two inflows, but very impractical for five or more - though I guess it could be scripted..)

PS: I realized that the figure has to work also black-and-white, so I need to use patterns. This made my manual stacking impossible, since the patterns have transparent backgrounds - until I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25032/10760) which showed how to combine patterns and fill, so I could get this:

[image]

Here is the full code for all the figures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
t   in1 in2 out
1   5   2   7
2   3   0   6
3   1   2   5
4   0   4   4
5   1   6   5
6   4   4   6
7   6   2   7
}\flowData

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[small,title=This is what I want,ybar,bar shift=0pt,]
        \addplot table[x=t,y expr={-\thisrow{out}}] {\flowData};
        \addplot table[x=t,y expr={\thisrow{in1}+\thisrow{in2}}] {\flowData};
        \addplot table[x=t,y expr={\thisrow{in2}}] {\flowData};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\ 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[small,title=First attempt using ybar stacked,ybar stacked]
        \addplot table[x=t,y expr={-\thisrow{out}}] {\flowData};
        \addplot table[x=t,y expr={\thisrow{out}+\thisrow{in1}}] {\flowData};
        \addplot table[x=t,y=in2] {\flowData};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[small,title=Check: using lines is OK,stack plots=y]
        \addplot table[x=t,y expr={-\thisrow{out}}] {\flowData};
        \addplot table[x=t,y expr={\thisrow{out}+\thisrow{in1}}] {\flowData};
        \addplot table[x=t,y=in2] {\flowData};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\ 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[small,title=Check: using area style is OK,stack plots=y,area style]
        \addplot table[x=t,y expr={-\thisrow{out}}] {\flowData} \closedcycle;
        \addplot table[x=t,y expr={\thisrow{out}+\thisrow{in1}}] {\flowData} \closedcycle;
        \addplot table[x=t,y=in2] {\flowData} \closedcycle;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[small,title=Test: only inflows,ybar stacked]
        \pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=1}
        \addplot table[x=t,y=in1] {\flowData};
        \addplot table[x=t,y=in2] {\flowData};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[small,title={Test: only inflows with ymin=-8},ybar stacked,ymin=-8]
        \pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=1}
        \addplot table[x=t,y=in1] {\flowData};
        \addplot table[x=t,y=in2] {\flowData};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{ % redefine the cycle list used for bar- and area plots
    /pgfplots/bar cycle list/.style={/pgfplots/cycle list={%
        {blue!80!black,fill=white,postaction={pattern=north east lines,pattern color=blue!75!white}},%
        {green!75!black,fill=white,postaction={pattern=crosshatch dots,pattern color=green!90!white}},%
        {red!80!black,fill=white,postaction={pattern=crosshatch,pattern color=red!67!white}}}
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[small,title={This is what I \emph{really} want},ybar,bar shift=0pt,]
        \addplot table[x=t,y expr={-\thisrow{out}}] {\flowData};
        \addplot table[x=t,y expr={\thisrow{in1}+\thisrow{in2}}] {\flowData};
        \addplot table[x=t,y expr={\thisrow{in2}}] {\flowData};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I understood your question right, than the following code does "what you *really* want", right? Since PGFPlots v1.13 this can be done quite easily with the new feature `stack negative=separate`.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
    \pgfplotsset{ % redefine the cycle list used for bar- and area plots
        /pgfplots/bar cycle list/.style={
            /pgfplots/cycle list={
                    blue!80!black,
                    fill=white,
                    postaction={
                        pattern=north east lines,
                        pattern color=blue!75!white,
                    }
                \\
                    green!75!black,
                    fill=white,
                    postaction={
                        pattern=crosshatch dots,
                        pattern color=green!90!white,
                    }
                \\
                    red!80!black,
                    fill=white,
                    postaction={
                        pattern=crosshatch,
                        pattern color=red!67!white,
                    }
                \\
            },
        },
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \pgfplotstableread{
                t   in1 in2 out
                1   5   2   7
                2   3   0   6
                3   1   2   5
                4   0   4   4
                5   1   6   5
                6   4   4   6
                7   6   2   7
            }\flowData
        \begin{axis}[
            small,
            ybar stacked,
            % use new feature from PGFPlots v1.13
            stack negative=separate,
        ]
            \addplot table [x=t,y expr={-\thisrow{out}}] {\flowData};
            % to produce your *really* wanted output, I had to reverse the
            % order of the `in' streams
            \addplot table [x=t,y=in2] {\flowData};
            \addplot table [x=t,y=in1] {\flowData};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: You are welcome. If you don't have already: Besides accepting the answer you could in addition [upvote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the answer by clicking on the up-arrow above the number on the left side of the answer.